# .net core3.1 + IdentityServer4 - One session per user

Tags: angular, identityserver4, .net-core-3.1

I'm new with IdentityServer and I'm facing some problems to solve the follow requirement:

- One user only can have 1 active session at the same time. I.e. if user A logs in in device 1 and then logs in in device B, the login of device 1 should change to logout.

I know, from what I read, that I'll need to put the logic on the server once IdentityServer cannot prevent this scenario but I'm not able to find the solution.
My difficultie is to know how can I notify the device 1 that his state has changed?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your exact scenario details, such as jwt or reference tokens, any client-side (front or back channel) sign-out implementation. One possible generic solution:

- 1 minute access_token ttl with refreshing each 3/4 minute.
- ```cs
  // right after await HttpContext.SignInAsync(identityServerUser);
  // in your [HttpPost]Login() action
  await _refreshTokenStore.RemoveAllAsync(new PersistedGrantFilter()
      {ClientId = context.Client.ClientId, SubjectId = user.SubjectId});
  ```

where `_refreshTokenStore` is your injected `IPersistedGrantStore`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 
Meanwhile I've implemented one workaround with signalR that will notify the first client to logout when a second client (with same credentials) try to login in a different endpoint.